# MongoDB query: Not getting the needed result in response

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to get only the users that are participants in the room , instead I'm getting all four users from the database. 
I've tried to do this in different ways, but every time I get all the users from the database table.

Here is the query code:

```
$data =  Channel::raw(function ($collection) {
          return $collection->aggregate([
            [
                '$match' => [
                    'is_default' => false,
                    'is_public' => false
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$lookup' => [
                    'from' => 'channel_messages',
                    'localField' => "ObjectId(_id)",
                    'foreignField' => "ObjectId(channel_id)",
                    'as' => "out"
                ]
            ],

            [
                '$unwind' => [
                    'path' => '$out',
                    'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true,
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$unwind' => [
                    'path' => '$out.readBy',
                    'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true,
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$lookup' => [
                    'from' => 'users',
                    'localField' => "ObjectId(participants)",
                    'foreignField' => "ObjectId(_id)",
                    'as' => "userDatas"
                ]
            ],
            [
              '$unwind' => [
                'path' => '$userDatas',
              ]
            ],
            [
              '$match' => [
                'userDatas' => [
                  '$ne' => []
                ]
              ]
            ],
            [
                '$group' => [
                    '_id' => [
                        '_id' => '$_id',
                        'title' => '$title',
                        'created_at' => '$created_at',
                    ],
                'participants' => [
                  '$addToSet' => '$participants',
                ],
                'userDatas' => [
                  '$addToSet' => '$userDatas',
                ],
                    'unreadCount' => [
                        '$sum' => [
                            '$cond' => [
                                ['$and' => [

                                    '$eq' => [ '$out.readBy.recipient' , 1  ],
                                    '$eq' => [ '$out.readBy.status' , false ]
                                          ]],

                                1,
                                0
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'lastMessage' => [
                        '$last' => '$out'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$project' => [
                    "_id" => '$_id._id',
                'participants' => '$participants',
                'userDataTotal' => [
                  '$size' => '$userDatas'
                ],
                'userData' => [
                  'data' => '$userDatas'
                 ],
                    "title" => '$_id.title',
                    'unread' => '$unreadCount',
                    'last_message' => '$lastMessage.message',
                    'created_at' => '$_id.created_at',
                ]
            ]

        ]);
    });
```

Here is the response I'm getting: 
 https://pastebin.com/iRCJQQe6 
What is wrong?

Here are the rows from  each of the three collections:  https://pastebin.com/8KzW9Sv5
Here are all the rows from the users table 
https://pastebin.com/xDWw7gD2

Comment: If I understand correctly, $userDatas should contain the two documents matching the two references stored in $participants. Can you cut the aggregator up to (including) the $lookup to the users table and paste the output ? It would be great also if you could add a sample document from your collection.

Comment: Thanks for adding documents, however there is only one document in your 'user' collection, and I would need all 4 users to reproduce the error, can you update the pastebin ?

Comment: Added all the rows from the users collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the correct results, you need to change two things in your code.

First, always store the ids references as ObjectIds, not as strings. For example, in your channels collection, instead of adding a record like this :

```
 db.channels.insert({
      "_id":"5ac8f99f536c829c915ca343",
      "title":"Chess",
      "user_id":"5aae67c9536c8220897d9c22",
      "is_public":false,
      "is_default":false,
      "participants" : [
             "5acb7305536c82042428abe6",
             "5aae67c9536c8220897d9c22"
      ],
      "color":"#03bf00",
      "created_at":"2018-04-07T17:02:23.000Z",
      "updated_at":"2018-04-07T17:02:23.000Z"}
 );
```

you should do :

```
db.channels.insert({
      "_id":ObjectId("5ac8f99f536c829c915ca343"),
      "title":"Chess",
      "user_id":ObjectId("5aae67c9536c8220897d9c22"),
      "is_public":false,
      "is_default":false,
      "participants" : [
             ObjectId("5acb7305536c82042428abe6"),
             ObjectId("5aae67c9536c8220897d9c22")
      ],
      "color":"#03bf00",
      "created_at":"2018-04-07T17:02:23.000Z",
      "updated_at":"2018-04-07T17:02:23.000Z"}
 );
```

And the same goes for all your other collections, 'users' and 'channel_messages'.

Second, in your lookup stage, change the "ObjectId(fieldname)" values and replace them with just "fieldname", like this :

```
        [
            '$lookup' => [
                'from' => 'users',
                'localField' => "participants",
                'foreignField' => "_id",
                'as' => "userDatas"
            ]
        ],
```

It will perform the lookup correctly and return you the 2 users expected, instead of every user stored in your collection.

At a more general level, Mongo is currently not allowing to convert ObjectIds() to strings ([issue SERVER-22781](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22781)), although it may be added in a future release. So if you want to be on the safe side, always stick to ObjectIds() in your queries/aggregators.

Comment: You're welcome, if you need more information, just ping me. In the meantime, can you please mark the answer as accepted as it solves your issue ?